# How to set nemo as default instead of nautilus?

Tags: unity, nautilus, search, nemo

I have recently installed `nemo` with:

```
sudo apt-get install nemo
```

But I am finding that other applications still are using `nautilus` to open folders like for instance the Unity search still opens its search results and folders in `nautilus`. So is there any way that I can get it to use `nemo` as default (at least the search)?

---

**OS Information:**

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

**Package Information:**

**Nautilus:**

```
nautilus:
  Installed: 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu15.1
  Candidate: 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu15.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu15.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.10.1-0ubuntu15 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages
```

**Nemo:**

```
nemo:
  Installed: 2.2.4-1
  Candidate: 2.2.4-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.4-1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Before changing defaults system-wide, you should thoroughly test something like a new file manager in one of your users first by adding nemo as the default file manager in the start-up applications...

**One user:**

Go to the dash, then type `startup applications` and add: by using `nemo -n` in the command.

Then disable Nautilus from drawing the desktop icons by executing:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

Log out and log back in and you'll see two identical "files" icons in the unity launcher.  Unlock the top one and lock the bottom one and move it to the top below the icon for the dash.  Then allow nemo to draw the desktop icons for you:

```
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true
```

**All users:**

Execute the following command:

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

and then edit `/etc/mime.types` and carefully review if nothing is left of `nautilus`.  If it is, replace it by `nemo`.

reboot afterwards.

Comment: You can also set `nemo` to manage the icons, using something like `gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true`

Comment: @Wilf: Answer edited.  Thanks for the info (and don't be afraid to edit my answers yourself next time!)  **;-)**

Comment: @dn-ʞɔɐqɹW I just fixed the gsettings command mentioned above

Comment: I tried this solution, and afterwards my wallpaper was not showing anymore. Any way to resolve this?

Comment: If you have a new question, please [ask one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and refer back to this answer. @BNJMNDDNN  (did you follow the process exactly and logged off and back on?)

Comment: I think this does not change the file-open function in applications. When I do file->open in thunderbird or chrome, nautilus appears.

Comment: If you have a new question, please [ask one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and refer back to this answer. @jms (did you follow the process exactly and logged off and back on?)

Comment: the file dialogs are from GTK toolkit, not from nemo or nautilus.