# How do I change the desktop background in Cinnamon?

Tags: cinnamon, desktop-background

I've changed my desktop environment to Cinnamon on 32 bit 15.04, the problem is that I can't seem to change my desktop background by going to `System Settings->Background` as I have selected a new background (several different ones I've tried to make sure it isn't just a bug affecting just one wallpaper) but no changes have occurred. I have also tried restarting Cinnamon (by the panel applet) in case the changes only occur after it is restarted and I did see the wallpaper I picked out while Cinnamon was restarting but once the restart had completed and I opened nautilus it went back to the old wallpaper I had before.

I rebooted my PC after attempting MiHa's answer and my background was the one I had wanted and then two system error messages appeared, leaving me with this desktop:
[image]

Notice how my desktop icons are doubled up. My unwanted background before I rebooted was:

[image]

and the one I wanted was:

[image: This]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why Nautilus changes the background. Nemo comes packaged with Cinnamon, but since you installed on top of Ubuntu, Nautilus is left as the default application. As such, some applications will call to Nautilus instead of Nemo, e.g. opening the Download directory from Chrome.

You can change your default file manager to Nemo by following:
[How to set nemo as default instead of nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605275/how-to-set-nemo-as-default-instead-of-nautilus)

Once you change your default file manager, you may have to change your desktop back to what you want and/or reset your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hack I had to do in order to change Ubuntu MATE lockscreen.

- locate the image which is set as your background (somewhere in `/usr/share/backgrounds/`)
- rename your desired picture, so the name is the same, as of the image located in `/usr/share/backgrounds/`
- rename original picture in `/usr/share/backgrounds/` to "picturebackup" or whatever you want
- copy your new image to that location
- restart (might not be necessary)

Cinnamon shouldn't act the way it does, but this way you might get temporary fix!

Comment: Didn't work I'm afraid. Just froze everything up, which left me no choice but to reboot.

Comment: well, I didn't expect that...

Comment: maybe try to do those steps in console `Ctrl+Alt+F2`, restart also from console ....see if it solves anything

Comment: I should mention the wallpaper I want was already in `/usr/share/backgrounds`.

Comment: In that case I would make copy of it.

Comment: You may wish to read my question again as I've added extra details. I don't like using console as I don't know how to exit it and go back into the GUI. Plus while I'm in there I can't read your instructions.

Comment: start from the beginning: Rename the image you wanted to it's original name first. Make copy of it and use that copy to carry out those changes. Sorry how it backfired, I haven't had any issues with this before!

Comment: you go back with `Ctrl+Alt+F7`, but I must agree that GUI is more user friendly.