# How to set PcManFm as the default file manager in 16.04?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, pcmanfm

Nautilus make my pc so slow, it keeps using more than 300MiB memory even after i close all folders... i installed PCMan file manager from software center and i like it.

but how can i set it as the default file manager in 16.04?

also `exo-preferred-applications` didn't work.

Comment: try the various answers here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/260244/make-nemo-the-default-file-browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I SOLVED USING THIS COMMAND:

```
xdg-mime default pcmanfm.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

and then edited `/etc/mime.types` and carefully review if nothing is left of nautilus. If it is, replaced it by **pcmanfm**.

[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/605283/699506)

Comment: This works in 20.04 as well !

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to settings manager.
2. Go to preferred applications folder/utilities tab.
3. Click on file manager.
4. Choose your file manager from the drop down menu.

This always works for me.